# React- fetch sends data to spring boot but then crashes program

Tags: java, reactjs, server, react-router

I'm writing my first full-stack app and I'm having issues getting my front-end (react) and my middle (spring-boot) to communicate properly.

Both are running on `localhost:8080`. I have a fetch in my react app that's meant to send data to my spring-boot app, and get a response status code back. The data is being sent successfully, but right afterwards the app crashes and I get the following error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for `error`, so you are
>   seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed May 15 22:01:47 EDT 2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

The error in the console is.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

i.e. what I want to be sent to the server is being sent, but the response that I expect to get back is being lost because the app crashes.
I'm really stuck here, if anyone could help me to understand what's happening I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you deliver your React application via Spring-Boot?

Comment: Yes it's static- I first build it using npm run build and then put it in my "public" folder in my spring boot app

Comment: Does your `fetch` hit the correct `@Controller` method?

Comment: It's calling the right method, if that's what you mean- I have printlns in the method that execute before my web app crashes

Comment: Are you familiar with Java? You could sorround the the code in the method with `try { ... } catch() { ... }` and print the stacktrace of the concrete exception.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how or why, but it suddenly started working right this second :) Thanks for the advice!